# Why would python dict's fromkeys method can accept a list as argument?

Tags: python, dictionary

Based on Python2.7
Is that keys of dict must be immutable and hashable? And inside the list implementation, i find that `__hash__=None`, which means it is not hashable.

And we could use `fromkeys` to create dict like this:

```
d={}.fromkeys(('Alice', 'Bob'),3000)
```

Because tuple is immutable and hashable.

But i also find this is ok:

```
d={}.fromkeys(['Alice', 'Bob'],3000)
```

That really confused me. Why would `fromkeys` accept a list as argument?
Is there an implicit from list to tuple?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the statement very carefully, based on what you wrote:

*keys of dict must be immutable*

The `fromkeys` method takes an *iterable*. From the docstring:

> Returns a new dict with keys from iterable and values equal to value.

You clearly provided two examples of this. What ends up happening is that the *items* in those iterables are *strings* which are *immutable*. It is those items that are going to be the keys of your dictionary.

Taking one of your examples, you can clearly see this from the output:

```
d={}.fromkeys(('Alice', 'Bob'),3000)
```

Output:

```
{'Alice': 3000, 'Bob': 3000}
```

If you had this, then you would get the expected error you think you should have gotten:

```
d={}.fromkeys((['Alice'], ['Bob']),3000)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/dev/rough/goo.py", line 31, in <module>
    d={}.fromkeys((['Alice'], ['Bob']),3000)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3):

[`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) will accept any [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) as an argument (this is [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)). The elements of the iterable will end up as dict keys.

```
>>> print(dict.fromkeys.__doc__)
Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value.
```

It's the elements of the iterable which need to be hashable, not the iterable itself.